# How to use If Else Condition in ng-class

Tags: angularjs

I am creating menu using angularJS. I need to add or remove class while click

my code shown below

```
<a href="#" ng-click="active='home'">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-home {active === 'home' ? 'fa-spin': ''}" ></i> Home </a>
```

I need to add and remove class (fa-spin) based on active value. But the above code was not working.

Answer (score 1):

Following is the correct syntax:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="active='home'">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-home" ng-class="{'fa-spin':active=='home'}"></i> Home </a>
```

**Suggestion**

Better use UI-router instead of making menu manually. UI-router has directives like `ui-sref-active` which will automatically add `active` class to active menu and remove from rest of the menu items

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  [ngClass]= "[active == 'home' ? 'fa-spin' : '']"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ngClass (See documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

The general syntax for the ng-class directive is as follows:

```
ng-class="{'class1': condition, 'class2':condition, ...'classn':condition}"
```

Therefore, your code should look like:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="active='home'">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-home" ng-class="{'fa-spin': active === 'home'}" ></i> Home </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<i ng-class="{'fa-spin': active === 'home'}" class="fa fa-home"></i>
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.